# Decoding an image from binary in rust

Tags: image, rust

I am playing with the youtube api and I would like to download the thumbnails and process them. I've managed to download them in binary doing a simple http request and I can save them as a .jepec file. What I would like to do is not having to save the image as a file and parse the binary directly into an image all in memory to avoid leaving files behind.
Any idea on hat do I need to do to accompish this?

Here is my code:

```rs
#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let res = reqwest::get("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/hqdefault.jpg")
        .await
        .unwrap();
    let bytes: Bytes = res.bytes().await.unwrap();

    let _ = fs::write("img.jpeg", bin.clone()); // this saves the image correctly

    let img = ????::from(bytes); // help here

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`jpeg_decoder` crate](https://docs.rs/jpeg-decoder/0.1.22/jpeg_decoder/struct.Decoder.html):

```rust
use jpeg_decoder::Decoder;

let mut decoder = Decoder::new(&*bytes);
let pixels = decoder.decode().expect("jpeg decoding failed");
let info = decoder.info().unwrap(); // image metadata
```

If you call `decode()` from an `async` function, you should do so in a blocking task using `tokio::spawn_blocking`, as `decode()` is not itself `async`.

Comment: Ty a lot, just a thing, I had to dereference the bytes: Decoder::new(&*bytes); I cannot make an edit bc its only one char.